# Multi Variable/Space Support for one Parameter (Skype bot)

Tags: c#, bots, parameters, skype

I have Been working on a Skype bot for a long time now.
*Please note, I am VERY Basic with the "C" Coding Languages.*
I use API's Fir the basic stuff such as Resolve or  Website up.. I can use them with no problem because they only require one parameter to work so i can just use "Params[1]". But for more difficult things like translator i need a different amount of variables. i may need to translate "Hello world" or "Translate this to English"

I need random amount of parameter support because i have it working fine with 1 word. if i say "!Translate Uno, Dos, Tres" it comes back with "One" because it does not recognize the second and third word as parameters. (I could add more Params[2] Params[3] etc. But every parameter would have to be filled in order for the command to even work.) It needs to be multi-Random variable support because it will be a random amount of words every time someone tries to use it..
It could be a paragraph or just a few words... Like i said.. needs random variable support.. OR to allow spaces without needing a new Param.

Here is my current code :

```
public static void Execute(string[] Params, int chat, string username)
{
    Skyper.SendMessage(chat, new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.c99.nl/translate.php?key=NOT_A_REAL_KEY&text=" + Params[1] + "&tolanguage=EN"));
}
```

That works for the first word but not anything after that. AS SHOWN HERE https://gyazo.com/942fa608bcbd8fc225759fce5da5ae6f
I need either a random Variable support OR So that it counts Spaces as a continued parameter.

I want to thank you ahead of time for helping me.
I am the kind of person that learns from his mistakes and i learn by watching someone do it then repeating it myself.

My SkypeBot is public. and i will be sure to put this site & the user that helped me in the credits! Thanks

Comment: Do you have your Api documentations?

Answer (score 0):

From the website, I see that the API can be used like this :
`http://api.c99.nl/translate.php?key=<key>&text=Hello World&tolanguage=EN`
That means it allows spaces. So why not just make your `Params` parameter a string? Then you can simply use "Hello world" as an argument. If you *must* use an array of words, just join them together with space as the separator:

`"http://api.c99.nl/translate.php?key=NOT_A_REAL_KEY&text=" + string.Join(" ", Params) + "&tolanguage=EN"`
Btw, replace spaces with "+" because query strings doesn't accept spaces.

Comment: Thanks! But now its translating the command as well..
Shown Here -->  https://gyazo.com/e00d7ec8140c182356e0e90881dffc58
I used your code, And it works.. i just don't want it to include the Command along with it.

Comment: just use string.Replace() to replace `!Translate` with ""

Comment: Sorry for the late response, But where would i implement that into my code?. I understand that your Idea will work, i just dont Know where to put " string.Replace" in my code to function properly.

I'm sorry, I'm very ignorant In this area.. I'm not trying to come off as rude, I really appreciate your help! I just need a little more help then you think lol.

Comment: No problem I can understand you :)
Do this : `string.Join(" ", Params).Replace("Translate","")`

Comment: I implemented it, and it seems to still do the same thing.
https://gyazo.com/601410801d18483b6a37aeb741d38ab7 . By looking at it , it should work,. but it doesn't seem too. Any other Ideas?

Comment: Current code = 
            Skyper.SendMessage(chat, new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.c99.nl/translate.php?key=NO_SHARING_CODES&text=" + string.Join(" ", Params).Replace("Translate","") + "&tolanguage=EN"));

Comment: What does `string.Join` return?

Comment: The command executes with no errors with "String,Join", It just includes the command with it when it translates.

Comment: make a variable `var s = string.Join(" ", Params);`, put a breakpoint at that point and check the value of it.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand. Like i said... Very basic, and can even be called a Noob. Please forgive my Inexperience. The guy that helped me. showed me how to download webstrings and use a single paramater and that was it. then i got stuff such as resolve, Isup, geo, shorten  working just fine because it only requires a single parameter or less...

Sorry for wasting your time like i am, Im just trying to learn and understand.

Comment: Haha, no problem. But I think you will need to learn more to proceed doe. Good luck :)